# Type Team does not conform to codable/decodable

Tags: swift, codable

I know this has been asked before and I thought I was following one of the answers given correctly but I am still getting a not conforming error on my struct:

```
struct Team:Codable {

var arrConference:[Conference]

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case arrConference = "conferences"
}

    struct Conference {

        var conferenceName:String
        var conferenceID:String

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case conferenceName = "alias"
            case conferenceID = "id"
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: To conform to a protocol you have to add it in the declaration line of **each** struct / class (see `Team`). And why do you name the name in `Conference` with `conferenceName` rather than just `name`? According to that pattern you should even name it `teamConferenceName`

Comment: doh...I am going to take a 'it's Sunday morning' defense...make it an answer so I can up you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have marked the outer struct `Team` as being `Codable` you have not marked the inner struct `Conference` as being `Codable`. When a `Team` is encoded, it attempts to encode its members, so its members must also conform to `Codable`

Because `Conference` it is just a pair of Strings, which already conform to `Codable`, that should take care of the issue. Or at least it compiled properly for me, in a quick and dirty test using Swift 4 at https://iswift.org/playground